# Setting a custom external IP address for Google Cloud VM instance to do web scraping

Tags: http, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, ip

I am trying to do web scraping using Google Cloud VM instance. However, the website I am trying to scraping is very sensitive so it has already blacklisted all the publicly-known IP addresses.

Even simply sending one GET request using `requests` is getting blacklisted. How can I set a custom IP address on my VM?

I have read GCP's own guides and tutorials but I am not sure I understand them correctly.

I am new to this whole cloud computing and IPs but I really want to make this work. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can set public IP address via reserving static ip addresses.

But it is not support "custom" ip address, You can just receive random ip addresses.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) to get information about how to reserve static ip address and attach it to VM instance.

In your case, It seems you will need a lot of ip addresses as
you have to attach different static ip address when sending every single request.

You can check your ip address quotas in [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&metric=%22Static%20IP%20addresses%22&_ga=2.124247758.551206842.1607907960-969369834.1590971021) before reserving a lot of addresses